# Há alguma maneira sem ser com HQL, de fazer update em massa com NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Estou necessitando fazer uma rotina que irá setar um *flag* em diversos registros que atenderem a alguns requisitos, e gostaria de manter isso no controle do **NHibernate**.

Entretanto, não encontrei nenhuma maneira de fazer um update em massa (*update batch*), com os recursos compiláveis e refatoráveis do **FluentNHibernate** (e **NHibernate**), não gostaria de partir para **HQL**, onde já percebi que é possível, mas perderia todas as vantagens da refatoração.

O que gostaria de fazer é algo bem simples, similar a isto em **SQL**:

```sql
UPDATE TABELAFLAGS SET COLUMNFLAG1 = 1 WHERE COLUMNFLAG2 = 2 AND COLUMNFLAG3 = 3
```

Que seria assim em **HQL**:

```c#
Session.CreateQuery(
@"update ClassFlags set flag1 = :p1 where flag2 = :p2 and flag3 = :p3"
).SetInt32("p1", 1).SetInt32("p2", 2).SetInt32("p3", 3).ExecuteUpdate();
```

**É possível fazer isso de maneira eficiente com `Session.Update()` ou algum outro método?**

Comment: é C# com FluentNHibernate ?

Comment: Sim, NHibernate é C#, em java é Hibernate. Vou adicionar a tag.

Comment: Sim só queria confirmar se era com C# @Fernando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atualmente com [NHibernate 5.0](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/releases/tag/5.0.0) foi incluído a seguinte funcionalidade: [Modifying entities inside the database](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html#querylinq-modifying), que implementa algo similar ao procurado na pergunta: [Updating entities](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html#querylinq-modifying-update), que seria a possibilidade de uma implementação similar a essa:

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
...    

session.Query<Cat>()
    .Where(c => c.BodyWeight > 20)
    .UpdateBuilder()
    .Set(c => c.BodyWeight, 20)
    .Update();
```

Que seria equivalente a um SQL como:

```sql
UPDATE Cat
SET BodyWeight = 20
WHERE BodyWeight > 20;
```

Answer (score 3):

Para que você faça um update em várias linhas você precisa resgatar essas linhas primeiramente, da sequinte forma:

***Classe Modelo***

```
public class Flags
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public virtual int Serie { get; set; }
}
//Mapeamento
public class FlagsMap: FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap<Flags>
{
    public FlagsMap()
    {
        Table("flags");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("id").GeneratedBy.Identity().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Quantidade).Column("quantidade").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Serie).Column("serie").Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

---

***Método de Pesquisa***

```
public IQueryable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T,bool>> Where)
{
    return Session.CreateCriteria<T>().List<T>().AsQueryable<T>().Where<T>(Where);
}
```

---

***Códificando, para trazer o Id de numero `1` e `2` e alterando a quantidade para `0`***

```
int[] Ids = new int[2]{1,2};
var lista = Query(x=>Ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
for(int i = 0; i < lista.Count(); i++){
        lista[i].Quantidade = 0;
}
Session.Flush();
```

Ou seja, trazendo os dados em cache e alterando seus dados e dando um `Session.Flush()`, ele faz um update em todas as linhas alteradas, então, não precisa usar HQL. Ele trabalha da mesma forma da maioria dos ORMs.

*Obs: eu retirei esse exemplo de uma camada própria com Repository bem estruturada e coloquei somente o que era necessária para essa resposta*

Comment: Essa abordagem vai ter um bom desempenho em grande escala, similar a implementação com HQL? Por em meus testes aqui verifiquei que ele irá fazer um `UPDATE` para cada registro, mas mesmo assim me pareceu bem eficiente. Ele executa todos os _updates_ em uma unica transação (_transaction_)?

Comment: Se você pesquisar 100 registros e mudar 10 registros e dá update em 10 registros, se você pesquisar 100 registros e fizer mudança em todos eles vão mudar todos, ele usa a transação atual para mudança! Em relação a performance vai depender bastante de vários cenários mas, usualmente, a gente faz assim  sem o HQL. Reforçando, ele é bem eficiente, funcional e performática vai depender de cenários !!!