# Fazer um update com lambda

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma consulta em lambda que me retorna uma lista de dados. Gostaria de saber como eu faço para atualizar essa tabela do BD usando lambda?

Digamos, eu tenho uma Tabela Chamada T_PDV e nele um campo flag, onde marco LIDO = 1 e se não for LIDO = 0. Esse campo, ao ser inserido registros nessa tabela, ele é marcado com 0. Após uma dada situação, ele deverá ser marcado com 1. Como eu faço esse update? O Update é somente nesse campo.

Comment: Você está utilizando algum ORM?

Comment: Pode colocar o código que traz a seleção do objeto, por favor?

Comment: tipo: update tabela set meu_campo = novo_valor, mas só que em lambda. Uso Entity 6

Comment: Cara, isso é uma **péssima** prática. Qual a necessidade de você fazer um *update* manual usando EF6?

Comment: @pnet analise as respostas e verifique se as mesmas respondem sua dúvida?

Comment: Então Morrison, o que realmente busco são boas práticas. Seu comentário gostei, mas esbarro em minhas limitações no uso e no conhecimento do EF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer um atualização em uma lista com [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397687.aspx) seria como nesse exemplo:

```cs
using (GenericsEntities db = new GenericsEntities())
{
    //Buscando as informações
    var dta = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2013");
    var dados = db.tbDatas.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Data) == dta).ToList();

    //Alterando as informações
    dados.ForEach(x =>
    {
        x.Data = x.Data.AddDays(-3),
        x.Nome = "Alterando nome";      
    });

    //Salvando as informações que foram alteradas
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

Ou seja, quando busco a informação, depois faça um `ForEach` e altere 1 ou mais campos e no final de um `SaveChanges();` Poderia ser feito um `For/ForEach` mais simples, mas, pela pergunta essa é forma `Lambda`

Comment: Uma pergunta bem básica. Com o db.SaveChanges(), realmente eu não dou um Insert? Essa é minha dúvida.

Comment: Insert só quando der um `add`, quando vc recupera é um update

Comment: Ok, então está mais que resolvido.

Answer (score 6):

### Update

No [NHibernate 5.0](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/releases/tag/5.0.0) foi incluído a seguinte funcionalidade: [Modifying entities inside the database](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html#querylinq-modifying), que implementa algo similar ao procurado nessa pergunta: [Updating entities](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html#querylinq-modifying-update), que seria a possibilidade de uma implementação similar a essa:

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
...    

session.Query<Cat>()
    .Where(c => c.BodyWeight > 20)
    .UpdateBuilder()
    .Set(c => c.BodyWeight, 20)
    .Update();
```

Que seria equivalente a um SQL como:

```sql
UPDATE Cat
SET BodyWeight = 20
WHERE BodyWeight > 20;
```

---

Acho que sei a resposta que você quer ler:

Com LINQ algo nessa ideia:

```
// Atenção isso não existe
(from entity in db.Registro update entity.Flag = 1 where entity.Id = 1).Apply();
```

Ou com Lambda algo similar a isso:

```
// Atenção isso também não existe
db.Registro.Where(t => t.Id = 1).Update(t => t.Flag = 1);
```

Mas infelizmente tenho uma má noticia a você:

Estas abordagens "ainda" não existem, então recomendo que siga as resposta já existem (a mais completa na minha opnião é a do [@HarryPotter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18924/fazer-um-update-com-lambda/18947#18947))

Eu também já procurei uma abordagem similar a sua com NHibernate, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16480/ha-alguma-maneira-sem-ser-com-hql-de-fazer-update-em-massa-com-nhibernate), e descobri que tanto Lambda quando Linq, são voltados a consultas (Query´s), e não a rotinas de "alteração nos dados";

Talvez em um futuro próximo, seja incorporado ao LINQ, ao LAMBDA e aos ORM´s algo que permita isso. Mas por enquanto a resposta é não, não há nenhuma forma.

No SOEN, também há posts falando sobre isso, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617827/linq-to-entities-how-to-update-a-record), com boas abordagens.

Answer (score 3):

```
        using (dbContext dataContext = new dbContext()) {
            StatusInteracao status = dataContext.StatusInteracao.Where(s => s.Login == login).SingleOrDefault();

            status.StatusVisitouCount = dataContext.Visitou.Where(v => v.LoginFoiVisitado == login).Count();               

            dataContext.StatusInteracao.Attach(status);
            dataContext.Entry(status).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            dataContext.SaveChanges();               
        }
```

Comment: Um exemplo bem simples de update. Obtenho o status (minha classe com vários atributos) e altero um dos atributos. Antes do "SaveChanges()" sinalizo que meu objeto sofreu uma alteração.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo completo de um controller Detalhar que atualiza um registro qualquer.
Ao entrar no registro, verifico se está tudo ok. Depois pego a PK (Chave primária) do registro e busco ele pelo Find. Se não achar gera um errro e vai para a Home do site.

O comando `UpdateModel`, pega os dados do model e coloca para a variavel `registro`. Depois é marcado como alterado o registro e salva ele no banco de dados.

Após disto tudo, mostro novamente o registro na view.

```
public ActionResult Detalhar(Registro model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      return View(model);

  using (var db = new ERPContext())
  {
      var registro = db.Registro.Find(model.RegistroID);    
      if (registro == null)
      {
          TempData["MsgRetornoError"] = "Registro não encontrado!";
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }

      UpdateModel(registro);    
      db.Entry(registro).State = EntityState.Modified;
      db.SaveChanges();

      if (btnSubmit == "Excluir")
          return RedirectToAction("Index", controller);

      return RedirectToAction("Detalhar", controller, new { id = model.RegistroID });
  }
}
```

Em lambda:

```
var registro = db.Registro.Where(w => w.RegistroID == model.RegistroID).First();
```

Comment: Ok, Marlon, mas isso não é lambda. Eu gostaria de saber como fazer com lambda expression.

Comment: Ajustado no meu post. Mas pq vc não usa Find? Find usa a PK da tabela. Se for composta, coloca todos os itens separados por ','

Comment: Gostaria de fechar esse post, mas não entendi direito ainda. Vou editar o post para entender melhor.